# Running Worker with node application in single deployment Kubernetes

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, rabbitmq

I have a node.js application and a worker that listens to my RabbitMQ events. I have my application on Kubernetes. I am trying to see if there is a way to optimize my deployment so that I can run my application and worker in the same deployment because I currently have to create different deployments with same docker image to run my deployment and my worker.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
    name: xxx-service
spec:
    replicas: 1
    selector:
        matchLabels:
            app: xxx-service
    template:
        metadata:
            labels:
                app: xxx-service
        spec:
            containers:
                - name: xxx-service
                  image: image:latest
                  ports:
                      - containerPort: 3004
                  env:
                      - name: PORT
                        value: '3004'
                      - name: SERVICE_NAME
                        value: 'xxx-service'
                      - name: WORKER_PORT
                        value: '3014'
                  imagePullPolicy: Always
                  readinessProbe:
                      httpGet: # make an HTTP request
                          port: 3004 # port to use
                          path: / # endpoint to hit
                          scheme: HTTP # or HTTPS
                      initialDelaySeconds: 180 # how long to wait before checking
                      periodSeconds: 20 # how long to wait between checks
                      successThreshold: 2 # how many successes to hit before accepting
                      failureThreshold: 3 # how many failures to accept before failing
                      timeoutSeconds: 2 # how long to wait for a responses
```

Then another deployment for my worker

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
    name: xxx-service-worker
spec:
    replicas: 1
    selector:
        matchLabels:
            app: xxx-service-worker
    template:
        metadata:
            labels:
                app: xxx-service-worker
        spec:
            containers:
                - name: xxx-service-worker
                  image: image:latest
                  command: ['yarn', 'start:worker']
                  ports:
                      - containerPort: 3014
                  env:
                      - name: PORT
                        value: '3014'
                      - name: SERVICE_NAME
                        value: 'xxx-service'
                      - name: WORKER_PORT
                        value: '3014'
                      
                  imagePullPolicy: Always
```

Would this be the best way or there's a better approach to do this because I do not want to waste resources.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, it would be managing both different workers and HTTP however yes some do manage the single deployment also.

**Multi-container single deployment**

it's better to use a single container in POD but you can run multiple containers also so single Deployment of one container worker and one container HTTP. (You have to take care of the service and labels)

Ref running multiple containers : https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/communicate-containers-same-pod-shared-volume/

**Code merge single Docker image**

Merge worker and Node code and let the Node manage to the worker process with **asyncs** on a time interval or so. (Not good idea but way is there)